# Reading and writing from/to ttyS0

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, c

I have a Raspberry PI Zero W connected to my virtual machine through USB, which can be found under `/dev/ttyS0` on both PC and the RPI. Currently I am trying to send something from the RPI through the USB cable to the virtual machine (PC).

I am trying to read on the port with the following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */    
    #include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */    
    #include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */    
    #include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */    
    #include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */    
    #include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */    

    /*     * 'open_port()' − Open serial port 1.     *     
    * Returns the file descriptor on success or −1 on error.     */    

   int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

   int open_port(void)    
   {            
     fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);   

     if(fd == -1) 
     {       
       /*        * Could not open the port.        */        
       perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 − ");      
     }      
     else        
      fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);      

    return (fd);    
  }

  int close_port(void)
  {
    close(fd);
    return (fd);
  }


  int main()
  {
    printf("Serial reader has started...\n\n");
    while(1)
    {
      open_port();
      close_port();
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

and on the RPI side, I have made a little bash script, which sends the character 1:

```
while :
do
    echo "sending character 1 to /dev/ttyS0"
    echo "1" > /dev/ttyS0
done
```

However, even though the bash script and the c program are both running in continuous loops, I am not receiving anything on the PC side.

What could be the reason?

**NOTE:**
The RPI is accessible through USB from the VM, since I am using SSH on the VM to access the RPI. So yes, the VM should already be configured to access the USB port.

**EDIT:**
I tried changing the code to this, where I implemented the function read(), however I still don't see any changes:

```
    #include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */    
    #include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */    
    #include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */    
    #include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */    
    #include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */    
    #include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */    

    /*     * 'open_port()' − Open serial port 1.     *     
    * Returns the file descriptor on success or −1 on error.     */    

   int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
   unsigned char bufptr;
   int reader;

   int open_port(void)    
   {            
     fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);   

     if(fd == -1) 
     {       
       /*        * Could not open the port.        */        
       perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 − ");      
     }      
     else
     {        
      fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
      reader = read(fd, &bufptr, 1);
        if (reader > 0)
        {
          write(STDOUT_FILENO, &bufptr, 1);  
        }
     }

    return (fd);    
  }

  int close_port(void)
  {
    close(fd);
    return (fd);
  }


  int main()
  {
    printf("Serial reader has started...\n\n");
    while(1)
    {
      open_port();
      close_port();
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You keep opening and immediately closing the port in an infinite loop, but never actually `read()` anything from it.

Comment: @telcoM
I thought fcntl() was for reading..

Comment: Also it is meaning less for close to return anything: The file descriptor can not be used, it is closed. I also recommend a different language, especial if you are getting started at programming. C is nice and small, but has some gotchas. Python is pretty good for beginners (however the exception mechanism is complex), golang is good for low-level stuff, but without C's gotchas.

Comment: The `fcntl()` call is with `F_SETFL`, so it is for setting the status flags; specifically, it's setting `FNDELAY` which is a synonym for `O_NDELAY` which should be already set by your `open()` earlier. Also, you don't capture `fcntl()`'s return value and its inputs are all constants (other than the file descriptor variable) so it *cannot* return anything to you when used that way. And it's in function named `open_port()`: if that function also reads anything from the port, the name of the function would be misleading.

Comment: @telcoM
See my edit, can you explain what I am doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

In your edit, you added the code to read from the port to the `open_port()` function. While it looks like it might work, that's bad style: now the `open_port()` function is specific to the needs of this program and is no longer easy to pick out and re-use in some future project without modifications. And the name of the function no longer accurately describes what the function does.

I am unconvinced that the set-up of your serial connection is correct: you say you're using a VM and that there is USB involved, but you seem to be using `/dev/ttyS0` on both ends. That refers to a physical serial port, not to USB-based one.

Maybe you have configured your virtualization software to connect an actual physical serial port or a serial port generated by the host's USB-serial converter driver to the VM's `/dev/ttyS0`: if that's true, then that might work on the PC side. But that is **not the default**: you must definitely configure that in your virtualization software or else it won't work.

A more common configuration would be to configure the virtualization software to allow the VM to access the USB side of a USB-serial converter as a whole: then it would appear in the VM as something like `/dev/ttyUSB0` instead (depending on the exact type of the serial converter).

On the RasPi side, `/dev/ttyS0` **does not exist** in the default configuration of the Pi Zero W - the typical serial port is `/dev/ttyAMA0`, but in the default configuration it is used by the Bluetooth functionality. If you've plugged in the USB side of the USB-serial converter to the RasPi, then it would appear as `/dev/ttyUSB0` here also.

Since your RasPi-side script does not check for the existence of the device, it may have created a file named `/dev/ttyS0`, containing a single line with number `1` in it. Run this command on the RasPi to see if its `/dev/ttyS0` is a valid serial device:

```
 test -c /dev/ttyS0 && echo "Maybe valid" || echo "Definitely not correct"
```

If you are using a physical serial connection (`/dev/ttyS0` or `/dev/ttyAMA0`) on the RasPi side, you should have 40-pin connector on the RasPi Zero W soldered in, and something plugged in to pins 8 and 10 of that connector, as far as I understand. You would also have had to use `raspi-config` to enable the serial port access.

If you can access the RasPi with SSH, that means you have a **network** connection: it tells nothing at all about the state of a **serial** connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible to use a path such as "/dev/bus/usb/003/007" on both the RPI and VM for both writing and reading?
When I run ```lsusb``` on the VM, I get ```Bus 003 Device 007: ...```, hence the path "/dev/bus/usb/003/007"

Comment: Also, when running ```test -c /dev/ttyS0 && echo "Maybe valid" || echo "Definitely not correct"``` on the RPI, it says that it is valid.
This should also be the case, since it is a "preconfigured" VM.

Comment: As far as I understand, the ```ttyAMA0```, is for the GPIO pins, but I want to use the USB for serial communication.

Comment: Did you mean it's a preconfigured RPI? Or are you running a VM on the RPI? I don't think I understand your configuration correctly.

Comment: I meant that it is a preconfigured VM running on my PC. And I control my RPI from the VM, which is on the PC, via SSH.